# Calling VS 2013 dll from VS 2008 dll

Tags: visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2013

I am planning to call (functions in) `VS2013` compiled dll from `VS2008` compiled. 
I am worried that this may fail (because dll format of `VS2013` may not be known to the older runtime) .
Both the exe and the `dll` are unmanaged `C++` .  My functions arguments only involve `int`, `double` , or `char *` . Is my apprehension unfounded? Are dll formats standard enough ( for these simple cases ) that it is (almost ) guaranteed to work. 
Note: I am talking about dynamically loaded dlls( no static linking is involved)

Comment: The "format" is not the problem, the issue that you have more than one version of the CRT in your program.  That has to be coded carefully, don't throw exceptions, don't return C++ objects, don't allocate in one module and destroy in another, don't rely on global CRT state like *errno* or locale.

Comment: @hans . Ok. Getting it( that format is not a problem). Do you mean that If I work under the above constraints it is highly likely it would work?

Comment: You cannot get a warranty here.  Test thoroughly.

Comment: Seems it is highly likely but not warrantied to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to call functions in VS2013 compiled dll from VS 2008 sucessfully.  (It was just like as I would in VS 2008. ) My concerns were unfounded.